# Get list of all runing processes (with processName+ProcessPath+ProcessTitle)

Tags: delphi, process, kernel, user32

what i'am trying to do:
get list of all runing processes with: `processName`(without `.exe`) `ProcessFullFilePath` `ProcessMainWindowTitle` something like:

```
process1 c:\p1.exe TheprocessTitle
..............
```

**Very important:**
i need working code that will not make any exception(`try catch`)


My Code:

i used `TLHelp32` to get list of the names:

```
var handler: THandle;
    data: TProcessEntry32;

  function GetName: string;
  var i:byte;
  begin
     Result := '';
     i := 0;
     while data.szExeFile[i] <> '' do
     begin
        Result := Result + data.szExeFile[i];
        Inc(i);
     end;
   end;
begin
    Application.ShowMainForm := False;
    handler := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, 0);
  if Process32First(handler, data) then
  begin
   ShowMessage(GetName());
    while Process32Next(handler, data) do
       ShowMessage(GetName());
   end;
```

it's not enough,
**i need: name path title**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too narrow

Answer (score 12):

This function is no good:

```
function GetName: string;
var i:byte;
begin
  Result := '';
  i := 0;
  while data.szExeFile[i] <> '' do
  begin
    Result := Result + data.szExeFile[i];
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that `data.szExeFile[i] <> ''` always evaluates `True`. That is because `data.szExeFile[i]` is a single character of type `char`, and `''` is the empty string which is never equal to a single character.

In fact you can implement `GetName` like this:

```
function GetName: string;
begin
  Result := data.szExeFile;
end;
```

You do also need to initialise `data` before you call `Process32First` as described in the documentation. You need to write:

```
data.dwSize := SizeOf(data);
```

before you call  `Process32First`.

Here is a debugged version of your program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, TlHelp32;

var
  Snapshot: THandle;
  pe: TProcessEntry32;

begin
  Snapshot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, 0);
  try
    pe.dwSize := SizeOf(pe);
    if Process32First(Snapshot, pe) then
      while Process32Next(Snapshot, pe) do
        Writeln(pe.szExeFile);
  finally
    CloseHandle(Snapshot);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Note that this will not give you the full path to the executable file. To get the full path you need to use `GetModuleFileNameEx`. That in turn needs a process handle which you get from the process ID by calling `OpenProcess`. And the process ID is found in the `TProcessEntry32` record.

As for the main window title, that's more tricky. Many processes will not have a main window. What's more even those that do, how to you know which window is the main window? A process may have multiple top level windows and only the application itself knows which one is conceptually the main window. In fact there may be no single main window. If there are two top level windows the application may have no preference for which one is the main window.

That said, what you can do is to enumerate all the top level windows with a call to `EnumWindows`. Then for each top level window call `GetWindowThreadProcessId`. This allows you to find out the process ID of the application that created each top-level window and from there you should be able to stitch together whatever information you decide that you need. So, that part of your question has no single definitive answer. You will need to work out exactly what you want before you progress.

Comment: ok, you helping me to fix existing code, thanks i fixed it.
but i prefer to write new code that can get the path of the exe , the name and the title, i don't want to fix the code i'am looking for new working code and then i will read the code and i will learn from him.
but now i need code :). By the way: you helped me before with dll injection.

Comment: Do you want me to write the code for you? In any case, the code in the answer is your starting point. It correctly enumerates processes. And I've told you how to do everything else.